# Duvidas quanto ao padrão Repository - Modelo Anemico - MVC

Tags: mvc, arquitetura-de-software, repository

Vejo muitas criticas ao modelo anemico de aplicação, por isso decidi tirar essa duvida.

Tenho duas aplicações ASP.NET MVC que poderiam compartilhar os mesmos Models (farão uso das mesmas propriedades e metodos)

Pensando em não reescrever ou copiar e colar toda essa galera, estive lendo sobre o padrão Repository nos links do Macoratti (são 3 artigos http://www.macoratti.net/15/11/net_repo1.htm), e vi que há uma separação entre a regra de negocio e as propriedades, deixando o modelo mais proximo do modelo anemico.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aparentemente resolveira meu problema inicial, pois eu criaria um camada de dominio (Models), e um repositorio onde colocaria minhas classes BLL, com regras de negocio e acesso a banco, e poderia reaproveitar essas DLL's no meu outro site

Alguem poderia me mostrar quais seriam os pontos ruins disso? Bem como se eu não estou me confundindo sobre o padrão Repository? Ou se existe uma outra saida para que eu não precise reescrever todas essas classes?

Answer (score 0):

O entendimento sobre o que é o padrão repositório e a afirmação de que o padrão Repository deixaria sua entidade anêmica ou mais anêmica é um equívoco.

A questão é a separação de responsabilidades.

Lembre-se, tudo é relativo e depende. Então estou presumindo que você queira usar um modelo rico. E portanto o resto da resposta vai se pautar em falar sobre esse objetivo.

Sua entidade deve saber o momento se persistir-se. No entanto, ela não deve saber como. Esse é o ponto. Como persistir é algo que revela tecnologias de acesso a dados, ORM's, ou serviços remotos, não importa qual seja a natureza da persistência.

O repositório sabe lidar com a persistência, com a parte de comunicação e integração com tecnologias que são específicas de acesso a dados. Isso não deve ser comportamento ou responsabilidade da sua entidade. Nem sob essa perspectiva, e só me recordo de active record como padrão que prevê algo parecido.

Então fica assim, sua entidade, sabe lidar com as regras de negócio que competem a ela, seu repositório sabe lidar com persistência.